# Constructors behaving strange with exception handling code

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exception, constructor

ScreenShot #1: Sample(Sample&) {...) // No Error without using "const"
[image]
ScreenShot #2: Destructor is called twice, when copy-constructor is not included.
[image]

When I run this code in VC++2010, I found results surprizing, please have a look:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Sample {
public:
   Sample() { cout<<"Sample().\n"; }
   // Sample (Sample&) { cout<<"Sample(Sample&).\n"; }
   ~Sample() { cout<<"~Sample().\n"; }
};

void fx() {
   throw Sample();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   try { fx(); }
   catch (Sample&) { cout<<"Caught Sample.\n"; }
   return 0;
}
```

Please tell why without including copy-constructor in example, destructor is being called twice. And having so causes Abort() if we're freeing heap in destructor for example.

Also I know that a copy of object is created of the throwing object, but why it is not calling copy-constructor for that.

Please see the attached screen shot for code and output.

Comment: First, it should be `class Sample {` not `class Sample() {`.

Comment: Also, the copy constructor should take a const reference, or you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: Can you show us your real code? When I compile and run that, I only see `Sample() - Caught_Sample - ~Sample -`. (with and without the copy constructor)

Comment: Here's your code running and confirming what Xymostech says: http://ideone.com/oe1uDF

Comment: Here's your code failing to compile when you uncomment *your* copy constructor: http://ideone.com/iFby5e

Comment: Here's your code running fine when you change the copy constructor to accept a const reference: http://ideone.com/fvxAS7

Comment: Please try this code in visual C++ 2010. I admit you all are right, it shouldn't be this way as i mentioned above. But trust me this is the REAL CODE i've typed in my IDE and TRUE RESULTS, i received, WITH NO ERROR or WARNING..

Comment: That's strange. I don't believe a non-const argument of a copy constructor can accept an unnamed, temporary variable as done in `throw Sample()`.

Comment: @Nawaz, why destructor can NEVER print any message.?

Comment: @ajay: Look at the destructor as to what it is printing, and compare it with the output. **Programmer should have sharp-eyes!**

Comment: @ajay. Look at what your destructor `cout` statement says: **"~Sample - "**. Then, look what you say the output is: **"~Sample()"**.

Comment: The code in your screenshot is different from the code that you posted in your question.

Comment: @everyone, whose abilities to detect typing errors got + above , please now explain code in screen shot.

Comment: @ajay: Now that makes some sense. Now show us the other screenshot when uncommenting the commented line.

Comment: now if you don't have answers to my questions, please remove your "-".

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug (feature? :) ) in the VC++ compiler which has been around for a while (I do not have any links to support this statement directly however and I don't have time to keep searching.  I think I have come across this one or twice myself though.)  This still occurs in VC++ 2012.

It is good coding practice to always define a copy ctor, even if you don't use it.  This is part of [The Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).  There are caveats though.

1. VC++ will use the context of the object not the caller when trying to execute the copy ctor when throwing.  So even if marked private it will still be accessible.  This is probably a legacy thing though I can't find anything specific to that fact.
2. VC++ will allow for a copy ctor with a non-const param when throwing.  This is also legacy to allow for shifting of resources around prior to the implementation of the move paradigm.  I only found a few things vaguely eluding to that.  And no, VC++ does not appear to use the move paradigm for throwing objects so this still occurs if you try and implement the move constructor.

For more info on the move constructor you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics).

Please note that Microsoft seems to cherry pick what part of the C++ standard it will implement based on if it will break too many things.  For this reason, I don't think I'd want to be on the compiler dev team at M$. :/

Comment: Is this deviation from the standard documented anywhere?